# CSS Styling for a Button: Using <input type="button> instead of <button>

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to style a button using `<input type="button">` instead of just `<button>`. With the code I have, the button extends all the way across the screen. I just want to be able to fit it to the text that it's in the button. Any ideas?

See the [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8bDux/) or continue on to the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>WTF</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 .button {
  color:#08233e;
  font:2.4em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size:70%;
  padding:14px;
  background:url(overlay.png) repeat-x center #ffcc00;
  background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
  border:1px solid #ffcc00;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 .button:hover {
  background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);
 }
</style>
<body>
 <div class="button">
  <input type="button" value="TELL ME MORE" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
 </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: you need to style input not the div around it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `.button` CSS, try `display:inline-block`.  See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w29DC/)

Answer (score 66):

Do you really want to style the `<div>`? Or do you want to style the `<input type="button">`? You should use the correct selector if you want the latter:

```
input[type=button] {
    color:#08233e;
    font:2.4em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size:70%;
    /* ... other rules ... */
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);
}
```

See also:

- [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bDux/2/)
- W3C: [CSS 3: 6.3 Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 6):

Do you want something like the given [fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/2RYyD/)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">
    <input type="button" value="TELL ME MORE" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button input[type="button"] {
    color:#08233e;
    font:2.4em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size:70%;
    padding:14px;
    background:url(overlay.png) repeat-x center #ffcc00;
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
    border:1px solid #ffcc00;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
.button input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Float:left`... Although I presume you want the input to be styled not the div?

```
.button input{
    color:#08233e;float:left;
    font:2.4em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size:70%;
    padding:14px;
    background:url(overlay.png) repeat-x center #ffcc00;
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
    border:1px solid #ffcc00;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    cursor:pointer;
}
.button input:hover{
    background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with the button, the issue is with the `div`. As `div`s are block elements, they default to occupying the full width of their parent element (as a general rule; I'm pretty sure there are some exceptions if you're messing around with different positioning schemes in one document that would cause it to occupy the full width of a higher element in the hierarchy).

Anyway, try adding `float: left;` to the rules for the `.button` selector. That will cause the `div` with class `button` to fit around the button, and would allow you to have multiple floated `div`s on the same line if you wanted more `div.button`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
Display:inline;
```

In the CSS.